# SAPUI5 creating, but not running preload files

Tags: sapui5

I have set up the following bootstap, with data-sap-ui-preload set to "auto"

```
<!-- Bootstrap the UI5 core library -->
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ushell, sap.collaboration"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-preload="auto"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='xxxxxxxxxxx'>
</script>
```

This creates a Component-preload.js file in all of my 3 separate apps.

Unfortunately, when I run it, the files aren't minified, and I can access the controller etc directly.

Has anyone else came across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you are expecting that "data-sap-ui-preload" creates additional files and also minifies the code. Is that correct?

If i read the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f1e3626f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm) correctly this is not what this parameter is used for.

If you are looking of ways on how to "minify" your could you should look into [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/). There is also a [UI5 Grunt task runner](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5) that is used by SAP itself.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes it looks like I've misunderstood what the preload is for. I'll look into Grunt. Many Thanks!